# Sylius redirect to specific URL

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have a route:

`some_route:
    path: /add/{token}
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: someController:createAction
        _sylius:
            template: 'sometwig.html.twig'
            redirect: 'HERE I WANT TO REDIRECT TO URL F.E. wwww.google.com`

and I want to redirect to a specific url, but as I know, you can only specify in redirect field another route name, not specific URL, so how to redirect to specific URL f.e. www.google.com?

`

Answer (score 0):

`redirect` attribute can only redirect to internal symfony route, you can only make custom route that always redirects to external absolute url